# Cypher - Delete node with given property and reconnect graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph consisting of paths.
[image]
I need to delete all nodes, that have a property:
    linksTo:'javascript' 
After deleting i have to reconnect the paths. This means i need to create a new relationship for each gap. This relationship has a property named deltaTime that holds some integer value. This value (deltaTime) should be the sum of all deltaTime-properties of the deleted relationships of this path. Please look at the following picture for better understanding.
[image]
I don't know how to detect multiple "bad" nodes in a row, with a variable row-length.

Comment: Can you confirm that all paths are chains where each node only has one incoming relationship and one outgoing relationship? If that doesn't hold true, then this can drastically change the queries that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you could provide the labels involved in your graph, as well as the relationship types you're using.

Assuming all these paths are chains (only single relationships connecting each node), something like this should work for you:

```
// first, add a label on all the nodes we plan on deleting
// it helps if they already have the same label especially if linksTo property is indexed.
MATCH (n{linksTo:'javascript'})
SET n:ToDelete
```

With the appropriate nodes labeled, we'll find the segments of nodes to delete, the surrounding nodes that need to be connected, and create the new relationship. We ensure a and b are start and end nodes of the chain by ensuring there are no :ToDelete nodes linking to a, or from b.

```
MATCH (a:ToDelete)
WHERE NOT (:ToDelete)-->(a)
AND ()-->(a)
MATCH p = (a)-[rel*0..]->(b:ToDelete)
WHERE ALL(node in nodes(p) WHERE node:ToDelete)
AND NOT (b)-->(:ToDelete)
AND (b)-->()
WITH a, b, REDUCE(s = 0, r IN rel | s + r.value) as sum
// now get the adjacent nodes we need to connect
MATCH (x)-[r1]->(a), (b)-[r2]->(y)
WITH x, y, sum + r1.value + r2.value AS sumValue
// making up relationship type and property name as I don't know what you're using
MERGE (x)-[:Rel{value: sumValue}]->(y)
```

Finally, when you're sure the new relationships look correct, delete the nodes you no longer need.

```
MATCH (n:ToDelete)
DETACH DELETE n
```

Comment: This is a very good answer and i am sure this could work. A have a poblem with the second part though. rel.value is a List of Relationships. SUM can't handle List<relationship> and throws a Type mismatch.

Comment: Good catch, forgot SUM() won't work on collections. One way around this is to UNWIND the collection of relationships and then use SUM(), but in this case I've replaced it with REDUCE, which we'll use to accumulate the sum.